# How to get litecoin address balance?

Tags: litecoin

I have an address :LUiTUnmBLQ6mvCXk2YNxiU7cZQdty1pToV
when I check it on http://block-explorer.com/address/LUiTUnmBLQ6mvCXk2YNxiU7cZQdty1pToV
I get Received: 1,199.9 LTC. is there another way to check it throw API or the wallet RPC ? 
keep in mind the address is not on my wallet but is from a wallet that is disconnected from internet.
I've tried to call method : 
￼
getreceivedbyaddress LUiTUnmBLQ6mvCXk2YNxiU7cZQdty1pToV 1
on my local wallet
but get zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sites that offer this kind of capability are running custom code and databases that parse more information from the block chain than what `litecoind` provides out-of-the-box. Right now, you would need a patch to `litecoind` to enable "watchonly" or setup an [ABE](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe).

Answer (score 1):

When I do

```
litecoind getreceivedbyaddress LUiTUnmBLQ6mvCXk2YNxiU7cZQdty1pToV
```

I get

```
0.00000000
```

I think this will always be 0.000 unless the address in your `wallet.dat`. One way would just be to include that addresses `wallet.dat` file in your `litecoind` directory and then just do

```
litecoind getbalance
```